# How to keep fixed width ticks on X-Axis in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I am using Line chart in react-chartjs-2 with labels of type Date. I have a dropdown to display 2 hrs, 4 hrs, 8 hrs charts. I want to maintain the distance between the X-Axis ticks of 15 mins. But in 4 hrs & 8 hrs I get the chart to be "smooshed". This smooshing problem will be solved if the distance between the ticks remain constant & instead the chart becomes horizontally scrollable.

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: "time",
      time: {
        unit: "hour"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this is throwing an error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"timeseries"'.`

This seems unexpected as I can verify that the labels I'm passing to the Line chart data param is an array of `new Date(timestamp)`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

maxTicksLimit will fix the number of ticks to get displayed, other way of doing it would be to use a call back function and returning only specific ticks with your own logic. You can also combine maxticksLimit with callback function if that suits you-

```
const option = {
     y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 10, // or the below
          callback: (val, index) => {
            return  index%{2} == 0 ? val: "";
          }
        }
      }
    }
```